# How to determine first instance of multiple items in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

The title doesn't describe this very well, but assuming the following simplified table in a Mysql 5 database:

```
 access

 access_id | ip        | date  | browser
 ---------------------------------------------  
 int       | char(40)  | date  | varchar(255)
```

how do I find the most optimal way to determine the number of first time users (by ip ignoring NAT routing and multiple people visiting from the same IP), and their browser visiting the site between a date range.  I.e.:

```
 SELECT count(browser), browser 
   FROM access 
 WHERE date > '2011-11-1' AND date < '2011-12-1' 
 AND ip NOT IN (SELECT ip FROM access WHERE date < '2011-11-1')
 GROUP BY browser
```

will give me all of the ips and browsers for users who have not visited the site before November 2011 -- however if a user has visited the site twice in November it will count them twice and I only want to count them once.  I think I can fix this with another ugly subselect, but I am looking for the most optimal way to perform the query as there are many rows in table.

Comment: I don't have access to a database at the moment but I assume you tried a SELECT DISTINCT(ip) and that didn't work?

Comment: DISTINCT and GROUP BY are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, MySQL can only do this using a correlated sub-query, or joining on a sub-query...

Correlated-Sub-Query:

```
SELECT
  count(browser), browser
FROM
  access
WHERE
      date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM access AS lookup WHERE ip = access.ip)
  AND date > '2011-11-1'
  AND date < '2011-12-1' 
GROUP BY
  browser
```

Sub-Query:

```
SELECT
  count(access.browser), access.browser
FROM
  (SELECT ip, MIN(date) AS date FROM access GROUP BY ip) AS lookup
INNER JOIN
  access
    ON  access.ip   = lookup.ip
    AND access.date = lookup.date
WHERE
      lookup.date > '2011-11-1'
  AND lookup.date < '2011-12-1' 
GROUP BY
  access.browser
```

Either way, be sue to have an index on `(ip, date)`

Comment: I was pretty sure I needed a sub query, I was just worried I needed two...  Thanks!

Comment: Just to note, the Correlated-Sub-Query is much more efficient.